# How can I retain whitespace in KornShell script when using backticks?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sqlplus, ksh

I am working on a script in KornShell (ksh).  My database connection is through SQLPLUS to an Oracle 9i database.  I have not had any problems getting DB values into shell variables, EXCEPT that any consecutive whitespace is automatically truncated to only one character.

**Here is an example of my code:**

```
MY_VAR=`sqlplus -s usr/pass@db << !
set heading off;
set pagesize 0;

select a_value from a_table where an_index = 25;
!`
```

**The actual data in the database is like this:**

```
Dec 15 09:19:10 <24:0070> User record (5    XATY       41839FG8   58775HK9AFF) is invalid for this condition
```

**My code example above returns it like this:**

```
Dec 15 09:19:10 <24:0070> User record (5 XATY 41839FG8 58775HK9AFF) is invalid for this condition
```

The spacing is critical for what I am working with.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, don't use backticks, they're deprecated per 'The New Kornshell Programming Language', published 1995! Instead, use the easy-to-nest version of command substitution, `$( yourCmd goes here)`.

You don't show us how you're using your variable $MY_VAR. If you saying

```
echo $MY_VAR > outputFile
```

You need to quote the variable, i.e.

```
print -- "$MY_VAR" > outputFile
```

`Print` is a ksh major-upgrade on echo, but it is best to have the habit of using '--' between the command and the strings you want to `print`. Any '-' char in the string you want to print can throw an unguarded (i.e. no '--'), `print` command for a loop.

You may also need to quote the assignment to MY_VAR, i.e.

```
MY_VAR="$(sqlplus -s usr/pass@db <<-EOD
set heading off;
set pagesize 0;

select a_value from a_table where an_index = 25;
EOD
)"
```

I've switched to EOD, as the ! char is used by many shells for notations like !$ (last word of previous line), so why confuse things.

Note for future: There is a tag for ksh that you can use here on StackOverflow. Shell is ver ambiguous, and can mean Windows cmd.com as well as zsh.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.  All I needed to do was put double quotes around the variable when using it and it solved all of my problems.